# My fugu in Hatch is surrounded by flies but there's no poo. She won't eat. What can I do?

Tags: hatch

My fugu in Hatch is surrounded by flies but there's no poo. She won't eat. What can I do to get rid of the flies so she can eat again.

Comment: having no clue what this game is about, the title sure is a WTF?

Answer (score 2):

Try quitting the app completely, by holding the Home button, and then swiping up on Hatch, and then restarting it.

Their official Twitter account [tweeted this](https://twitter.com/Hatch/status/403683906165035008) yesterday:

> If you have flies that don't go away please try relaunching me from
>   your iOS multitasker!

Answer (score 0):

Check around there is a purple bag of poo that missed the trash :(  That's what happened on mine anyway